# How to create a column based of a column with empty rows as delimiters in R

Tags: r, nested-loops, apply, lapply

I am trying to create a column based of another with empty rows as delimiter, here are my tables.

```
      TABLE1     TABLE2
V1  V2  INDEX      V1
U   30    1        30
V    3    2        54
V   25    3        61
V    4    4         6
          5         .
U    54   6         .
V    9    7         .
V    22   8        
V    90   9        
         10        
U    61  11
.     .  .
.     .  .
```

Now I am trying to get something like this,

```
      TABLE1
V1  V2  INDEX  MATCH         
U   30    1    30        
V    3    2    30        
V   25    3    30        
V    4    4    30         
          5         
U    54   6    54     
V    9    7    54     
V    22   8    54    
V    90   9    54    
         10        
U    61  11    61 
.     .  .     61
.     .  .     .
```

I was thinking in using  *dist(rbind())* to find the distance between the index of *V1[i]=U* and the blank row in the index that would give me the number times to use *apply()* or a for loop to create the MATCH column.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible approach using `data.table` combined with `zoo`

```
library(data.table) ; library(zoo) # loading the packages
setkey(setDT(TABLE1), V2) # converting to `data.table` object and setting a key for a binary join
TABLE1[TABLE2, MATCH := i.V1] # conducting binary join (I'm assuming the column in TABLE2 called "V1") and updating MATCH by reference
setorder(TABLE1, INDEX, na.last = TRUE) # reordering back by INDEX
TABLE1[, MATCH := na.locf(MATCH)] # filling the NAs with the previous value in MATCH
#     V1 V2 INDEX MATCH
#  1:  U 30     1    30
#  2:  V  3     2    30
#  3:  V 25     3    30
#  4:  V  4     4    30
#  5:    NA     5    30
#  6:  U 54     6    54
#  7:  V  9     7    54
#  8:  V 22     8    54
#  9:  V 90     9    54
# 10:    NA    10    54
# 11:  U 61    11    61
```

---

**DATA**

```
TABLE1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "U", "V"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(30L, 
3L, 25L, 4L, NA, 54L, 9L, 22L, 90L, NA, 61L), INDEX = 1:11), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "INDEX"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

TABLE2 <- structure(list(V1 = c(30L, 54L, 61L, 6L)), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and comments. This is what I was looking for. But still I am not getting it right, I am getting the match but not the same for all the entries before the blank row.

Comment: This worked, thanks you so much. I was having problems changing the data.frame to data.table.